# Sublime Text 3 macro to delete x lines from caret

Tags: macros, automation, sublimetext3

I'm wanting to create a Sublime Text 3 macro to select 111 lines from the cursor and delete them. I tried recording this, but all it did was delete one character backwards, which I'm still confused by. I then looked into writing the macro manually, and the relevant commands [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/commands.html), but I've still not been able to figure out from that page whether what I want is possible, and if it is, how. Would really appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no internal Sublime Text command that will do multiple moves at once, unfortunately. However it is possible to define your own movement command via plugin code, which allows you to work around that.

To go this route, select `Tools > Developer > New Plugin...` from the menu and replace the default code with the following, then save the file as a python file (e.g. `move_repeat.py`). By using the menu entry to do this, Sublime will ensure that your plugin is stored in your `User` package.

```python
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class MoveRepeatCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, repeat=1, **kwargs):
        for num in range(repeat):
            self.view.run_command("move", kwargs)
```

This implements a new command named `move_repeat` which is a drop in replacement for the `move` command, providing an extra argument of `repeat` that specifies how many times to perform the movement that you provide.

As a drop in replacement, this can be used for any cursor movement (lines, words, etc).

Using this, your macro becomes the following:

```json
[
    {
        "command": "move_repeat",
        "args":
        {
            "by": "lines",
            "extend": true,
            "forward": true,
            "repeat": 111
        }
    },
    {
        "command": "left_delete"
    }
]
```

Here I just created the macro by hand-coding it. If you wanted to do this with an actual macro recording you would need to go about that another way.

For example, you could record the macro going down only one line and deleting, then manually add the extra value after the fact, or you could bind a key binding to the repeated command first and then do a macro recording.

Comment: Thanks so much! It hadn't even entered my mind that ST3 wouldn't allow for repeating of commands, and it's odd that it doesn't ship with a way to do so, but this is a brilliant solution. I just came back to this question at the right time because I've since found yet another need to repeat a macro command. One question - will replacing the `run_command("move")` with another command work for repeating other commands, or is it specifically designed to work with `move`?

Comment: The way it's written it will repeat whatever command you put into the `run_command`, yes. Although you might want to also rename the class as well in that case so the command name makes more sense.

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I wanted to hear. One more thing - how would this function if you repeated it for an arbitrary large number and it came to the end of the document? I'm currently looking for something that'll stop running as soon as it comes to the end of the document s as to ensure any further lines aren't deleted, but don't know how this will behave in that scenario.

Comment: If you try to move down e.g. 100 times but there are only 9 lines left, then it will run the move an extra 91 times but they won't do anything, so at worst you're just wasting time. If you wanted the entire macro to stop and not do anything, that is a little more involved. I don't think you can terminate a macro that way. In that case you may be better off writing a custom command that does everything instead, so that it could check along the way to see if it's still OK to keep running.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for all your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

## The Messy Way

I've since managed to figure out a way to record macros. For some reason, the recorder doesn't register text selection by mouse, so I had to select the text via keyboard shortcut while recording the macro. This does the job in that it creates the macro I describe, although it also results in a script that I'm guessing is far less elegant than it would be if written by someone in the know.

Here's a shortened version of the script I ended up with:

```
[
    {
    "args":
    {
        "by": "lines",
        "extend": true,
        "forward": true
    },
    "command": "move"
},
{
    "args":
    {
        "by": "lines",
        "extend": true,
        "forward": true
    },
    "command": "move"
},
{
    "args":
    {
        "by": "lines",
        "extend": true,
        "forward": true
    },
    "command": "move"
},
{
    "args":
    {
        "by": "lines",
        "extend": true,
        "forward": true
    },
    "command": "move"
},
{
    "args":
    {
        "by": "lines",
        "extend": true,
        "forward": true
    },
    "command": "move"
},
{
    "args": null,
    "command": "left_delete"
}
]
```

It's as crude as it gets. It works by using the `move` command to select one line at a time. This means that this command block **needs to be repeated for each line that you want to select for deletion**. In my case, I needed 111 of them. Hopefully someone will come along and offer a nicer solution, but until then, this does the job.